# How to combine an amount of money with the compound interest function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Tommy has some money at home from his graduation modeled by the function $h(x)=350$. He read about a bank that has savings accounts that accrue interest according to the function 
>   $s(x)= 1.04 ^{x-1}$. Tommy is thinking about putting his money into the savings account to gain interest. Explain to Tommy how he can combine his functions to create a new function. What does the new function mean.

I am sure I am overthinking this. Combining functions confuse me. Would it be $h(x)+s(x)$? Not sure what it would look like. Does the new function just mean that is how much interest he gained after choosing a particular savings account?

Comment: If this is really how the problem was given to you, it's understandable that you would be confused.  It's not clear to me what it means to accrue interest "according to the function $s(x) = 104^{x-1}$."  My best guess is that $s(x)$ is the factor by which the initial balance will have grown after $x-1$ years.  I don't know why $x-1$ is being used instead of $x$.  Probably for a real-word example $1.04$ should be used instead of $104$; then the equation would correspond to $4\%$ interest, compounded annually.  Was it a typo?

Comment: In any case, if $1.04^x$ is the factor by which the money has grown after $x$ years, then you multiply (not add) this by the initial deposit to get the account balance after $x$ years.

Comment: By the way, this problem makes me mad.  Why should we "explain to Tommy how he can combine his functions to make a new function"?  That is a silly way to explain compound interest.  And treating the initial balance of 350, which is a constant, as a function is just creating confusion for no reason.

Comment: Also, how can we explain to Tommy what the new function means if we don't even know what the old functions mean?  The only way I can guess what $x$ is supposed to mean is by having previously done problems that were similar but better-posed.  Grrr.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537761/combining-functions-with-growth asked using a duplicate account.

Answer (score 1):

What they are asking you is basically to apply "Combination of functions" . Multiply the two functions to get $350(1.04)^{x-1}$. This new function means an explicit equation for geometric sequences. VOILA.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

h(x) is the principal to multiply with as a coefficient, $x$ is time. It can be re-cast into standard form for compound interest.